# How to fill the messages in gRPC?

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm new on gRPC. I'm using it with C++. I already defined my message in a proto file as:

```
message Buffer {
    bytes data = 1;
    int32 size = 2;
}
```

My question is: I have a `uint8_t buffer[size]` to put inside of that message, how can I do it?

Comment: Isn't that what `repeated` is for in gRPC? Note that you don't send C++ pointer values across the network, as that would be pointless. Rather, you send arrays of values.

Comment: Sure, I'll correct the question. Anyway, how can I do that using arrays of values?

Comment: Hmm, now, your question indicates you only want a single `uint8_t` value. Is it really just one value or an array?

Comment: An array of size = x. I'll correct again... LOL...

Comment: Check this out: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#specifying-field-rules. gRPC uses protobuf as metaformat underneath, so that's the documentation you need to read.

Comment: I read. The closest solution I found was using bytes which is the same as string. That is the best aproach?